# Wordpress Forbidden

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I just installed `wordpress` on my `cPanel`, and when I upload `plugins` or `themes` it generates a `403 Forbidden error`,

Previously, I experienced the same thing when saving the settings of one of the plugins, but did not meet the solution. so I tried to reinstall my `wordpress` with the help of softaculus but still get the `403 Forbidden error`

But on the previous day, my `wordpress` site was fine.

It's just a few hours ago when I wanted to upload a `plugin` and it generated a `403 Forbidden error`.

In this problem, I use a multi-site on my website, and here are the contents of the `.htaccess` file that is on my website.

```sh
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    
    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

please help me solve this problem

[image]

Comment: Most probably modsecurity rule is causing this issue. You have to whitelist rule in the WHM.

Answer (score 0):

So recently, I met this issue while working on a `WordPress` installation using `apache2` on the server on `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Using `cPanel`, get into the command-line.
Log into the server directly there and do something like this:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/YOUR-DIRECTORY
```

---

***Here's a bit more context into the issue:**

The above command gives ownership of all the files [in that folder] to the www-data user and group. This is the user that the Apache web server runs as, and Apache will need to be able to read and write WordPress files in order to serve the website and perform automatic updates.

Be sure to point to your server’s relevant directory (replace YOUR-DIRECTORY with your actual folder).

This [article from digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04) should help you understand what is being done here.